# How do i make the "Send email" button work in a Boostrap template?

Tags: html, django, templates, bootstrap-4

For my website, i use a free template form startbootstrap.com, in this template there is a "Send Mail" button, i tried to get it running, but it doest, work. How can i make it work?

I have already changed the  mailto@something.com to my real email and it didnt work. I am not very experienced in web developing, so it might be a very simple thing. Any help would be much appreciated

Here is the code section for the email part: \n
The only line i changed was :

> action="mailto:myreal@mail.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">

This section tells me that i should configure my web server differently if things dont work, how would i do that

> ```
>       <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
> ```

I expected this part, to just send an email to me from the provided email addres with the given content, but when i try to run it it says:

Sorry, it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use a server-side to send email by connecting your smtp server and send yourself the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which template you have chosen, but with "Freelancer" there's a contact_me.php located under mail folder, where you should configure this part:

```
$to = "yourname@yourdomain.com"; // Add your email address inbetween the "" replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$header = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$header .= "Reply-To: $email";
```

Since you need php and mail server for this to work, after configuration you can deploy it to a server like xampp or wampp if you'd like to test it locally or just copy it to a real webserver.

Comment: I cant find the mail the contact_me.php file, i see it referenced in files like contact_me.js, could you tell me where i could find the required file?

Comment: There should be a line like this around your email form:
<!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->

which one do you use?

Comment: If you mean the template, i use this one:  https://startbootstrap.com/themes/freelancer/

Comment: I tried finding the file @scrach suggested, but i cant find it, i see it referenced in contact_me.js as "url: "././mail/contact_me.php" but even with this i dont even find a file with .php files in the static folder. What am i doing wrong=